# Authorize.NET Simple checkout form

Tags: php, api, authorize.net

I am new with Authorize.NET, however i have been integrating paypal in many of the sites..
Paypal have this simple way of integration in which we can simply put some html form code which then take care of rest of the transaction with paypal
For e.g: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_prepopulate_outside

My question is, does authorize.NET have some sort of similar HTML code which i just put in and it takes all the fields and send it to authorize.NET account.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Checkout is not the same.  The merchant must pre-configure the details and the developer must insert the HTML generated in the Merchant Interface into the appropriate location on the page.